# Wait screen until document added to Firestore subcollection?

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-animation

I am make random chat app with Flutter and Firestore.

When first user want to chat, I want show wait screen (CircularProgressIndicator). When second user join chat, I want show main chat screen.

But how can I make client app listen continuous for user2 to join? Base on my Firestore schema it must listen for user2 to join `/roomUsers` subcollection (user2 is add as document name UID). This subcollection already have data for first user so cannot just listen if subcollection hasdata.

@jurrdb has post this code on stackoverflow:

```
class MyScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MyScreenState createState() => _MyScreenState();
}

class _MyScreenState extends State<MyScreen> {
  Widget _screen;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _screen = CircularProgressIndicator();

    _doSomeFirebaseChecking();
  }

  void _doSomeFirebaseChecking() async {
    // Add your code that performs checks at Firebase here.

    // Then use setState to update the widget to a screen of choice.
    setState(() {

    });
  }
}
```

I am try use this model but no know how to make client app check Firestore subcollection continuous.

I have try get documents from `/roomUsers` subcollection and check if `documentSnapshot.length > 1` but this only run once so not update when user2 join chatroom.

How can solve this? I am try streambuilder/futurebuilder but no solve.

Thanks!

Update: Here how I write "user document" into the roomUsers subcollection:

```
roomUsersRef = Firestore.instance.collection(‘chats').document(docID).collection(‘roomUsers').document(uid);
await roomUsersRef.setData({
  ‘user2UID': uid,
});
```

Comment: You can either listen for the specific document of the second user, or you can listen to all documents in the subcollection and then perform an additional client-side check for the second (user's) document. It's impossible to say which one is better based on what you've shared so far. For better answers, consider showing how you actually write the "user document" into the `roomUsers` subcollection.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks! I have update with how I write "user document" into the roomUsers subcollection. I no think can listen for specific document of second user because I not know before what user2 uid is

Comment: Correct. So in that case you'll have to listen on the entire subcollection (which should never be more documents than the number of users in a chat), and filter client-side.